# Unable to connect to ssh on Google Cloud Platform:

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are unable to connect to 'VM'via ssh instance on Google Cloud platform. 
Here we are trying with the help of 'SSH' button available on the browser.

But following message is received:
We are unable to connect to the VM on the port 22.

We have tried to Stop and Start the VM but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a firewall rule that enables SSH access on port 22 for your VMs. It is better to make the 'Target' as a network tag instead of enabling SSH access for all of the machines on your VPC network.

You can use the CLI to perform this operation - using the default VPC

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create <rule-name> --allow tcp:22 --network "default" --source-ranges "<source-range>"
```